# Fail2ban not finding or banning IPs

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, logging, regex, fail2ban

Fail2ban version v0.10.2

I have a simple jail that looks for a specific user agent.

```
[barkrowler]
enabled = true
filter = barkrowler
logpath = /var/log/apache2/proxy.mydomain.com.access.log
port = 80,81,8103,8203,8303
maxretry = 1 
findtime = 10
bantime = 86400
action = iptables-allports[name=barkrowler]
```

The `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/barkrowler.conf` file

```
[Definition]
failregex=^.*\| <HOST> .*Barkrowler.*
```

A typical access log line from this user agent

```
[2020-10-13 14:23:09 (Tue)] | server20 | R:- | www.mydomain.com | 62.210.78.76 |"GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" | 301 | 249 | 80 | "-" | "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Barkrowler/0.9; +https://babbar.tech/crawler)"
```

`fail2ban-regex` shows me it matches

```
root@server20:/etc/fail2ban# fail2ban-regex --print-all-matched /var/log/apache2/proxy.mydomain.com.access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/barkrowler.conf 

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : barkrowler, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /var/log/apache2/proxy.mydomain.com.access.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 1354 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1354] ^.*\| <HOST> .*Barkrowler.*
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1106761] {^LN-BEG}ExYear(?P<_sep>[-/.])Month(?P=_sep)Day(?:T|  ?)24hour:Minute:Second(?:[.,]Microseconds)?(?:\s*Zone offset)?
`-
```

Any idea of what could be wrong? My backend is pyinotify and time is correct.

```
root@server20:/etc/fail2ban# timedatectl
                      Local time: Tue 2020-10-13 14:47:37 CDT
                  Universal time: Tue 2020-10-13 19:47:37 UTC
                        RTC time: Tue 2020-10-13 19:47:37
                       Time zone: America/Chicago (CDT, -0500)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Fail2ban log never says anything beyond this when it's started:

`2020-10-13 14:17:45,055 fail2ban.jail           [18459]: INFO    Jail 'barkrowler' started`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my problem was related to the `findtime` portion of my jail. Observing the log hits, I realized they were more spaced out than fail2ban was detecting (1-2 minutes apart). I changed it to `findtime = 120`, and it began banning.

So, anyone out there having this problem, if the rest of your configs are correct, and your regex is sound, pay attention to these (`findtime` and `maxretry`).